# "git reset hard" before my first commit

Tags: git

I was trying to set up a git repo, and right after I did `git init`, I wanted to add everything in my folders, but at the last second after `git add .` I did `git reset --hard`

Is there any way to retrieve those files?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the contents back, they're all in `.git/objects` because you did `git add`.  Recovering the file names won't work since you never wrote a tree before wiping the index, but run [`git fsck --lost-found`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fsck.html) to get what you can.

Comment: I'm getting this:

Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling commit 96d411747e922bd8ace34d9c0a4ac599fa0d1366
dangling tree f26b6ccda17707871833b3a360dd4d2dd12e6456

Comment: Look in `.git/lost-found`

Comment: Dangling commit?  That's odd, I don't recall git doing any commits without being asked. Try `git checkout 96d4117`, see what that gets you.

Comment: Wait, that commit is from something else.

Comment: these are commits I made after the fact... :(